# How to get src link to image? (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, image, src

I want to get src link to image, but instead of that i am getting a link to attachment page.

I use this code in functions.php file:

```
function show_all_thumbs() {
    global $post;
    $post = get_post($post);

/* image code */
$images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&output=ARRAY_N&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&post_parent='.$post->ID); 
if($images){
foreach( $images as $imageID => $imagePost ){

unset($the_b_img);
$the_b_img = wp_get_attachment_image($imageID, 'thumbnail', false);
$thumblist .= '<a target="_blank" href="'.get_attachment_link($imageID).'">'.$the_b_img.'</a>';

}
}
return $thumblist;
}
```

So how to change this line to get src link to image:

```
<a target="_blank" href="'.get_attachment_link($imageID).'">
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) returns an array, the first item of which holds the src:

```
$src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $imageID, 'thumbnail', false );
```

usage:

```
<a target="_blank" href="' . $src[0] . '">
```

Comment: In fact, the function does NOT always return an array.  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/